# Java Regex to get 11 words before and after specific word recursively

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to get 11 words before and after a specific word in String.

For Ex:

```
and WINSOCK 2.0 in Visual Studio 2012/2013, compiled as Release for use on 64-bit and 32-bit Windows Servers. Client application discovers and validates qualifying Windows Server product
```

Now here the challenge is to identify word like 32 which is connected to word bit with hyhen. If I change this word to 32+bit instead of 32-bit... the regex identifies and gets me 11 word before and after the sentence.

My regex looks like

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(?<!-)\\b(?<!&)(" + "\\b" + word + "\\b" + ")(?!&)\\b(?!-)(?:[^a-zA-Z'-]+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,11}");
```

I seek any help in this.

**PS Note* I am not able to identify words attached with hyphen**

**@Solution** Thanks to @Wiktor

```
\\b(?<!&)\\b" + word + "\\b(?!&)(?:[^a-zA-Z']+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,11}
```

Thanks.

Comment: So do you want 32-bit to be recognised as 1 or 2 words?

Comment: I want to identify only word 32.. The pattern should be matched.. I don't need the complete word {32-bit}. Thanks

Comment: So `32-bit` should be recognised as `32` *and* `bit`?

Comment: Then why include hyphens at all? `"\\b(?<!&)\\b" + word + "\\b(?!&)(?:[^a-zA-Z']+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,11}"` should work then

Comment: @Nick I need to get the context of word 32 from any String and highlight that .. Now in  my case .. as 32 is present in the string it should be matched and and application level it will be highlighted(Only word 32 will be highlighted) ..

Comment: output like this 32+bit

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your solution did worked.. May you please explain that so that I can fit that to my needs..

Comment: I just removed the hyphen "from the equation". Oh, one `\b` is redundant there. Use `"\\b(?<!&)" + word + "\\b(?!&)(?:[^a-zA-Z']+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,11}"`

Comment: Ohhh okay ... Let me try that.

Comment: With such a question, you should start with a definition of "word", 2012/2013 is one word or two? Are you limited to use regular expressions? Personally I do not think it's the best way to go... What if there is less than 11 words before, after?

Comment: @Betlista I am totally unknown to Regex... {0,NUM_OF_WORDS}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may "take out" the hyphen from the regex:

```
"\\b(?<!&)" + word + "\\b(?!&)(?:[^a-zA-Z']+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,11}"
```

Or, if the word may start/end with special chars:

```
"(?<![&\\w])" + Pattern.quote(word) + "(?![&\\w])(?:[^a-zA-Z']+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,11}"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tdkGk5/1)

**Details**

- `\b(?<!&)` - a word boundary that is not preceded with `&`
- `word` - a variable word (note you may need to escape it with `Pattern.quote(word)` or even replace `"\\b(?<!&)" + word + "\\b(?!&)"` with `"(?<![&\\w])" + word + "(?![&\\w])"` if the `word` may start/end with special chars)
- `\b(?!&)`  - a word boundary that is not followed with `&`
- `(?:[^a-zA-Z']+[a-zA-Z'-]+){0,11}` - 0 or more sequences of:

  - `[^a-zA-Z']+` - 1+ chars other than ASCII letters or `'`
  - `[a-zA-Z'-]+` - 1+ ASCII letters or `'`.

Comment: I added a variation of the regex that will be useful if your `word` may start/end with a special regex metacharacter (like `(`, `[`, `+`, etc.)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Your explanation is of great help to me. I hope it will be helpful for  people like me who are totally unaware of Regex.

Answer (score 0):

if you have not to use regex, then :

```
String message = "and WINSOCK 2.0 in Visual Studio 2012/2013, compiled as Release for use on 64-bit and 32-bit Windows Servers. Client application discovers and validates qualifying Windows Server product";


String target = "32-bit";
int index = message.indexOf("32-bit");
int lenght = target.length();

String before = message.substring(index -11, index);
String after = message.substring(index + lenght , index + lenght + 11);

Log.i("tag", "index: " + index);
Log.i("tag", "before: " + before);
Log.i("tag", "after: " + after);
```